# azure kubernetes dashboard not configured

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a cluster configured on azure kubernetes . and the services are working fine.
following this article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-dashboard

i am trying to view dashboard using but get the error as follows

```
az aks browse --resource-group DemoRG--name aksdemo2

Proxy running on http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Press CTRL+C to close the tunnel...
Error: unknown flag: --address
```

My cluster does not have RBAC enabled , i am unsure if this is related to network issue or something different.

Comment: There is  no space between the name of your rg and the --name flag, should be `az aks browse --resource-group DemoRG --name aksdemo2`. Don't know if that is causing the issue.

Comment: You can add the parameter `--debug` to get the details of the error.

Comment: i solved this by following https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8642
I had two copies of kubectl and the one from docker was overriding the one from azure. found this by firing "where kubect" from command prompt. and deleting the docker copy.

Comment: You can add an answer to describe the reason for who also meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Eventaully issue was resolved by author of this post by following existing github [issue #8642](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8642):

> I had two copies of kubectl and the one from docker was overriding the
>   one from azure.  Found this by firing "where kubectl" from command
>   prompt, and deleting the docker copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just run kubectl proxy then go to following URL

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/#!/overview?namespace=default

I used kubectl proxy to access the dashboard